# Square-free grows as $6n/\pi^2$: $k$-th free?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

The asymptotic number of
[square-free numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Distribution)
$\le n$ is $Q(n) = 6n/\pi^2 + O(\sqrt{n})$.
Because
[$\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeta2.html),
$Q(n) \approx n/\zeta(2)$.

[OEIS A004709](http://oeis.org/A004709)
says that cube-free numbers have asymptotic density of
$1/\zeta(3)$, "the reciprocal of
[Apery's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AperysConstant.html)"
("the probability that three randomly chosen integers are relatively prime":
[link here](http://oeis.org/A088453)).

> ***Q***. Are there analogous results or conjectures for $k^{\textrm{th}}$-power-free numbers?, $k>3$?
>   Does the density continue to $1/\zeta(k)$? Is that conjectured or proven or disproven?

I ask this in (obvious) number-theoretic naiveté.

---

**Answered** by Gjergji Zaimi and Douglas Zare and Noam Elkies: the density indeed grows
as $1/\zeta(k)$, and this has been established.

Comment: Yes, your guess of $1/\zeta(k)$ is correct :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_order_of_an_arithmetic_function#The_density_of_the_k-th_power_free_integers_in_N

Comment: The analogue holds for the probability that $k$ randomly chosen positive integers (up to $n$, then let $n\to \infty$) are relatively prime. J.E Nymann. "On the probability that k positive integers are relatively prime." Journal of Number Theory
Volume 4, Issue 5, October 1972, Pages 469–473. A similar result is known for the probability that $k$ positive integers are pairwise coprime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it works in much the same way for any $k$.  Here's an elementary proof.

Let $Q_k(n)$ be the number of $k$-th power free integers $\leq n$.
Then
$$
Q_k(n) = \sum_{d^k \leq n} \mu(d) \lfloor n/d^k \rfloor
= \sum_{d^k \leq n} \mu(d) \, (n/d^k + \theta_d)
$$
for some $\theta_d \in [0,1)$.  Hence 
$$
\Bigl| \, Q_k(n) - \sum_{d^k \leq n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^k} n \, \Bigr| < n^{1/k}.
$$
But $\sum_{d^k \leq n} \mu(d)/d^k$ is a partial sum of
a series that converges to $1/\zeta(k)$, with error bounded by
$\sum_{d^k > n} 1/d^k \ll n^{1/k}/n$.  Therefore $Q_k(n) = n/\zeta(k) + O(n^{1/k})$,
**QED**.

Comment: It's even true for $k=1$ (and with a much better error term) ;-)